# unable to access internet from windows in VMware guest OS

Tags: windows, wireless-networking, internet, vmware

I'm using windows 7. I have installed vmware. In vmware i have installed guest OS(windows). Now i want to access internet in my guest OS. How can i access? Please suggest me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Has your Virtual Machine got network interface drivers installed?  Also, have you made sure that you have created a network interface on the Virtual Machine settings?  Finally, what Virtual Platform are you using; VMWare, Oracle Virtualbox etc...?

Comment: @James  im Using VMWare platform. i dont have any idea about network interface drivers and also about network interface settings in VMWare. Could you please point me to any link?

Comment: Have a look at this site: https://www.vmware.com/support/ws55/doc/ws_net_configurations_changing_vadapters.html, each version of VMWare Player/Workstation is pretty similar.  Once you've done this, you may need to install network device drivers on your virtual machine, however try the above first and let us know how you get on.

Comment: @James i'm vmware version 11. The link you pointed to the VMware is 5.5.  Could please give me another link for version 11.

Comment: @VenkatKondeti That part of Workstation hasn't substantially changed since VMware Workstation 5.5.

Comment: @VenkatKondeti as James has said, the differences between the versions are negligible, however for future reference, please give more information in your question; especially version numbers to help us tailor our answers to you :)

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to VM > Settings > Hardware and add a network adapter if one is not already present.
2. Configure the VM's network adapter to use [NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation) to reuse your host's IP address. (You may wish to use bridged networking instead, which will make your VM appear as a physical machine on your local network and which will be a bit faster, but this can be a little trickier for wireless networks or if your host has multiple network adapters.) You can click the Help button in the VM Settings dialog for more information.